# Create multidimensional array based on value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7

I've spent hours trying to find the answer to this question, but I'm struggling. I'm reasonably familiar with PHP and the various in-built functions, and can build a complex foreach() loop to do this, but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has a smarter solution to my problem.
I have an array in this form, Now I want to convert this into multidimensional based on list_id matched on next instance.I  tried this solution but not worked well https://stackoverflow.com/a/65042103/4626270.
This may be duplicate but not got output here

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [list_id] => 5
            [order_list_name] => meri list 3
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [list_id] => 5
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [product_name] => DUCHESS WHITE WINE 200 ml
                    [sku] => SKU0001
                    [qty] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [list_id] => 5
            [order_list_name] => meri list 3
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [list_id] => 5
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [product_name] => CONNEXION DOUBLE ROCK 350 ml, Pack of 2
                    [sku] => SKU0002
                    [qty] => 8
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [list_id] => 7
            [order_list_name] => meri list 9
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [list_id] => 7
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [product_name] => CONNEXION DOUBLE ROCK 350 ml, Pack of 2
                    [sku] => SKU0002
                    [qty] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I am expecting output like this

```
<pre>Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [list_id] => 5
                [order_list_name] => meri list 3
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [list_id] => 5
                        [product_id] => 1
                        [product_name] => DUCHESS WHITE WINE 200 ml
                        [sku] => SKU0001
                        [qty] => 2
                    ),
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [list_id] => 5
                        [product_id] => 1
                        [product_name] => DUCHESS WHITE WINE 200 ml
                        [sku] => SKU0001
                        [qty] => 2
                )
    
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [list_id] => 7
                [order_list_name] => meri list 9
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [list_id] => 7
                        [product_id] => 2
                        [product_name] => CONNEXION DOUBLE ROCK 350 ml, Pack of 2
                        [sku] => SKU0002
                        [qty] => 2
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: Can you give us an input as a string? so we can easily copy it.

Comment: This is in my code 
$recordNew = array('list_id' => $record['list_id'], 'order_list_name' => $record['order_list_name'], ['list_id' => $record['list_id'], 'product_id' => $product->getId(), 'product_name' => $product->getName(), 'sku' => $product->getSku(), 'qty' => $record['qty']]);

Comment: Edit your question instead of post here in the comment, and provide us full example (so array fullfilled)

Comment: Please present your sample data as `var_export()` (preferred) or a json string so that volunteers can instantly use it in their preferred test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use temporary first level keys based on list_id to form groups.  When finished, remove the temporary keys with `array_values()`.

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$record['list_id']])) {
        $grouped[$record['list_id']] = [
            'list_id' => $record['list_id'],
            'order_list_name' => $record['order_list_name']
        ];
    }
    $grouped[$record['list_id']][] = [
        'list_id' => $record['list_id'],
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'product_name' => $product->getName(),
        'sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'qty' => $record['qty']
    ];
}
var_export(
    array_values($grouped)
);
```

Removing the condition will also deliver the same result; it will just keep silently overwriting the two associative elements.

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $grouped[$record['list_id']]['list_id'] = $record['list_id'];
    $grouped[$record['list_id']]['order_list_name'] = $record['order_list_name'];
    $grouped[$record['list_id']][] = [
        'list_id' => $record['list_id'],
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'product_name' => $product->getName(),
        'sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'qty' => $record['qty']
    ];
}
var_export(
    array_values($grouped)
);
```